# Move a shape to a different layer

Tags: vba, visio

I tried to record a macro to move a selected shape from one Visio Layer to another.  The Recorded macro only works on the original shape.

I found an example on this site of code used to assign a selected shape to a layer

```
Dim myLayer As Visio.Layer
Set myLayer = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Layers.Add("Layer1")
myLayer.Add Application.ActiveWindow.Selection(1), 1
```

But I also want to remove the selected shape from an existing layer, called Layer0

```
Dim myLayer As Visio.Layer
Set myLayer = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Layers.Remove("Layer0")
myLayer.Add Application.ActiveWindow.Selection(1), 1
```

I was hopping that I could substitute the .Add with .Remove but that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I got help. What I was asking for was very simple,  I was putting the .remove parameter on the wrong line. corrected version now works

```
' to add selected ojbect to Layer1
Dim myLayer As Visio.Layer
Set myLayer = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Layers.Add("Layer1")
myLayer.Add Application.ActiveWindow.Selection(1), 1


' to remvoe selectec ojbected from Layer0
Dim RemoveLayer As Visio.Layer
Set RemoveLayer = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Layers.Add("Layer0")
RemoveLayer.remove Application.ActiveWindow.Selection(1), 1
```